# AngularJS controller not called from html

Tags: angularjs, controller

If anyone can help, I'd be very thankful. I am pretty new to AngularJS and trying to learn it. The problem I got is that one of controllers are not called when button Bought is pressed

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="AlreadyBoughtController as Items">
                <h2>Already Bought:</h2>
                <ul ng-repeat="bought in Items.ItemsBought track by $index">
                    <li>Bought {{bought.quantity}} {{bought.name}}</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="emptyMessage" ng-if="Items.ItemsBought.length === 0">Nothing bought yet.</div>
            </div>.
```

Please look complete code with app.js file on plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8wKY7PPZ6mINsFGCJQfP?p=preview

Comment: You can debug this by placing `{{ Items }}` somewhere under where you define `AlreadyBoughtController as Items` -- you'll see the CTRL is actually getting loaded fine, but adding a 'bought' item comes in as null.  http://embed.plnkr.co/Mhoa50ClNcbOPbC1D2Py/ Error is coming from your implementation to add bought items.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but I need someone to explain me why it is coming as null and what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you were never actually passing the index of the item you bought.

```
<li>Buy {{item.quantity}} {{item.name}} <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="itemsToBuy.boughtItems($index);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Bought</button></li>
```

Pass `$index` to your function: `ng-click="itemsToBuy.boughtItems($index);`

Take a look at the fixed [plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/c4FHGNWNKVwCMaASWD4X?p=preview)

Comment: Aniket, thank you very much. I knew it had to be something simple, yet I could not figure out. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: Nothing says thanks better than an accepted answer/upvote. :)